# Somar valores de selects diferentes

Tags: sql, asp

Bom dia A todos, tenho duas select, estou exibindo uma ao lado da outra, preciso somar o valor de uma select com o da outra ..isso é possível? as duas select sao tabelas distintas, eu estou exibindo um valor ao lado do outro, mas preciso somar esses valores...por favor se alguém souber fazer preciso de ajuda.
segue o código dos select:

```
Set objConn =  Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("banco.mdb") & ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}","username","password"
strQ = "SELECT * FROM Vendas2017 ORDER BY id asc"
Set ObjRs = objConn.Execute(strQ)


Set objConn2 =  Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn2.Open "DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("banco.mdb") & ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}","username","password"
strQ2 = "SELECT * FROM Vendas2018 ORDER BY id asc"
Set ObjRs2 = objConn2.Execute(strQ2)
```

Comment: olá, é totalmente possível mas não seria mais prático você somar no banco de dados e já retornar o valor somando com um query? De qualquer forma, pra te ajudar mostre os nomes dos campos que você quer somar, só `select *` sem saber a estrutura da tabela não ajuda muito

Comment: Ola Ricardo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, seria isso que vc precisa? 
<br/>
<br/>
strQ = "SELECT * FROM Vendas2017 ORDER BY id asc"
<br/>
strQ2 = "SELECT * FROM Vendas2018 ORDER BY id asc"
<br/>
tabela01:  Vendas2017
tabela02:  Vendas2018
<br/>
nome da coluna tabela 01: janvalor
nome da coluna tabela 02: janvalor
<br/>

Comment: você editou a pergunta e perdeu o texto que explicava... seria legal você voltar como estava e só acrescentar na pergunta os nomes das colunas...

Comment: mais uma dúvida, cada um desses `select` retorna quantas linhas? porque se as tabelas *Vendas2017* e *Vendas2018* retornarem muitas linhas, o `SUM` no banco, ou mesmo somando no código, o resultado pode ser muito grande e dar erro de *overflow*

Comment: desculpe, eu não acostumei ainda com o site, exatamente isso que esta acontecendo Ricardo deu overflow, sao 5000 linhas, tudo que eu queria é colocar um valor ao lado do outro e somar

Comment: Suspeitei que podia acontecer isso... :)
Qual o tipo de dados do campo *janvalor*?

Comment: Você pode usar a função `CDec` para ajudar se seu não campo não for `decimal`:
`select sum(CDec(janvalor)) janvalor`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode somar direto no banco usando uma terceira `query`, que seria assim:

```
select sum(janvalor) as Soma from 
(
     select sum(janvalor) janvalor from Vendas2017 
     union
     select sum(janvalor) janvalor from Vendas2018 
) as Vendas
```

Ou também somar no código, mas ai precisa um laço `for` ou `foreach` pra ler os registros e somar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo fazer isso com uma determinada estratégia. Mais fácil mostrar que explicar. Suponha que eu queira comparar vendas de anos diferentes mês a mês:

`select mes,
         sum(iif(ano = 2017, valor, 0)) Ex2017,
         sum(iif(ano = 2018, valor, 0)) Ex2018
  from   vendas
  group by mes;`